# What to do when wiredep doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bower, wiredep

I've recently started using bower and wiredep.
These guys play nicely together and usually work a treat.

I've come across the odd occasion where wiredep is not able to add the dependency, a recent example is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "slimScroll": "https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll.git#~1.3.6",
  }
```

Is there a way to help wiredep wire these dependencies?

Comment: Define what "doesn't work" means. Have you read the official stance on this? https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#what-can-go-wrong

Comment: Thanks, probably a poor choice of words as wiredep is no doubt doing all that it can. Thanks for the link. In this case the package did not specify a main property in the bower.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this was down voted.

The problem in this instance was that the package did not specify a main property in the bower.json

For anyone interested you can add an override to your bower.json, adding in the main that was missing from the original package.

```
"overrides": {
        "slimScroll":{
          "main":["jquery.slimscroll.js"]
        }
      }
```

Just saw another example: The bootstrap 3.3.5 bower package does not reference any css files in the main property as a result wiredep can't add the css.

Answer (score 0):

`Wiredep` checks `bower.json` of every package and based on that, performs the operation. If there's no dependency information then wiredep simply ignores the package.

You can manually add those file or try alternative - `inject`.